# configuring spray.can.client in a library

Tags: akka, spray

I'm writing an http service client library using spray can client, which uses akka io.

In order for the client to work properly, I need to set some non-default `spray.can.config` config options (I need to set `respone-chunk-aggregation-limit = 0` to handle large chunked responses correctly).

I'd like 1) to bundle this setting into the client somehow so users of the library don't have to do any explicit config, and 2) have it only apply within my client library's use of spray client, not inadvertently misconfigure things in case users of the client library are using spray client elsewhere (which I know they're likely to be doing -- our org uses spray in most all of our projects in a SOA setup).

Since a spray-can-client isn't a configured class instance, and because it's coupled in a way I don't completely understand with `akka.io.IO`, I'm not sure where or how configuration happens.  (Is the spray.can.client configuration part of the actor system configuration it's using?  That would seem weird to me.)

Anyway, if anyone's done anything like this or has any advice, would love to hear about it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you are actually using spray client in your application. In any case, all of the config settings can also be configured at runtime. See [`ClientConnectionSettings`](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-can/src/main/scala/spray/can/client/ClientConnectionSettings.scala) and [`HostConnectorSettings`](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-can/src/main/scala/spray/can/client/HostConnectorSettings.scala).

Each of the request-level API, connection-level API, and host-level API allow you to specify those settings.

```
val customSettings = ClientConnectionSettings(system)
```

Connection-level:

```
IO(Http) ! Http.Connect("www.spray.io", port = 8080, settings = Some(customSettings))
```

Host-level:

```
val customHostSettings = HostConnectorSettings(system).copy(connectionSettings = customSettings)
IO(Http) ! Http.HostConnectorSetup("www.spray.io", port = 80, settings = customHostSettings)
```

Request-level:

```
IO(Http) ? (HttpRequest(GET, Uri("http://spray.io")), customHostSettings)
```

Comment: `ClientConncetionSettings`/`HostConnectorSettings` is exactly what I was lookginf for.  Thanks!